# Spring WebFlux: How to store a file in a R2DBC database (PostgreSQL)?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, r2dbc-postgresql

Tried everything I could think of in order to store a file in a table with WebFlux and a R2DBC PostgresDriver without success, while it work with in a non reactive way with SpringMVC.

**Non reactive**

Controller

```java
    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseMessage> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
      String message = "";
      try {
        storageService.store(file);
        message = "Uploaded the file successfully: " + file.getOriginalFilename();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
      } catch (Exception e) {
        message = "Could not upload the file: " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(new ResponseMessage(message));
      }
    }
```

Service

```java
    public FileDB store(MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
      String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
      FileDB FileDB = new FileDB(fileName, file.getContentType(), file.getBytes());
      return fileDBRepository.save(FileDB);
    }
```

Postman

[image: Client]

DB

[image: PostgreSQL]

**Reactive**

Controller

```java
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public Mono<Certificate> uploadFile(@RequestPart("file") Mono<FilePart> file) {
        return file.flatMap(this.service::store);
    }
```

Service

```java
    public Mono<Certificate> store(FilePart file) {
        try {
            String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.filename());
            Certificate cert = new Certificate();
            // cert.setCertificate(file.getBytes());
            cert.setFileName(fileName);
            // cert.setFileType(file.getContentType());
            return repository.save(cert);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return Mono.empty();
         }
    }
```

DB

[image: Reactive]

**Question**

The Reactive code allows me to store the file name but I'm unable to get the `byte[]` out of the `FilePart`.

Using `MultiPart` instead of `FilePart` will throw a `application/PDF format not supported`
I tried to use a `Flux` instead of a `Mono`, or to use `@RequestBody`, `@RequestPart` without  success.

Could someone tell me how to get a `byte[]` out of a `FilePart` without saving a file to the disk, or any other way to do it ?

Comment: you most likely cant get a `byte[]` since then we need to block to get all the bytes of fixed n size. Instead `filePart.content().asByteBuffer()` to get a buffer for streming data. its all in the api description for filepart. Also try/catch is commonly not used in webflux. The database will not throw exceptions, it will most likely return a `Mono#error` when failing.

Comment: Any success on this?